# Use a stored user (no sign in) to access Microsoft Graph API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-office, access-token, credentials, microsoft-graph-api

When using the Graph API normally you first ask the user to sign in. I want to have a user `master` that has access to read/write the calendars of all other users in the tenant (this is already done). 
I want the credentials (userName and password) of `master` to be stored in my app (webconfig) so that I can make calls to an endpoint that edits users calendars using the `master` user, without any manual sign-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MS Graph is an oauth based application, what you are looking for is called `App-only` access. This is described in detail here. https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app-only.

The advantages of this is that as new users get added or their password change  you don't need to update your configuration. In addition, it much secure since you don't have to deal with passwords at all.